# Get the requested page

Tags: php, errordocument

Is there any way with `.htaccess` to send to the `404 page` also the requested page ?

so in other words let say I'm requesting a non existing page like :

```
domain.com/nonexistingpage.php
```

goes to

```
domain.com/404.html?requested=nonexistingpage.php
```

this is my current .htaccess line so it goes to 404.html

```
ErrorDocument 404  /404.html
```

I want to know what to add to get the results like this :

```
domain.com/404.html?requested=nonexistingpage.php
```

instead of :

```
domain.com/404.html
```

Comment: Yes, it can be done, in that case you just need to make some configurations to your server, that way you can edit your own default error pages. And in that case instead of displaying those default pages it will display your custom pages.

Answer (score 0):

There's normally no need to do so. You can grab the requested page from PHP itself:

```
$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

I'd recommend the latter since it also contains the query string.

Comment: Not working... I'm getting nothing... Here is my code :

        <?php
        echo 'REDIRECT_URL : '.$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'];
        echo '<br>';
        echo 'REQUEST_URI : '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        ?>

I'm getting no results:

go to mastering.tw/blablabla.php and you will be redirected to mastering.tw now go to the bottom page and see the results :

REDIRECT_URL :
REQUEST_URI : / 

Not working...

Answer (score 0):

If your aim is just to get the requested url, you can use

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

or

```
$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']
```

Comment: Not working... I'm getting nothing... Here is my code :

        <?php
        echo 'REDIRECT_URL : '.$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'];
        echo '<br>';
        echo 'REQUEST_URI : '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        ?>

I'm getting no results:

go to mastering.tw/blablabla.php and you will be redirected to mastering.tw now go to the bottom page and see the results :

REDIRECT_URL :
REQUEST_URI : / 

Not working...

Comment: You've tagged your question as PHP so I was assuming that your site is using PHP. It's obvious that your server is not configured to run PHP in your *.html files.

Comment: In that case I'm redirecting to the index.php and it's not working... take a look at mastering.tw just type some unknown page mastering.tw/notexistingpage.php and you will be redirected to the index.php see the results on the bottom page.